# how to select range of time of a variable from netcdf using python

Tags: numpy, time, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a daily netcdf data containing a point data of single lat and lon. The shape of vairable (`var.shape`) is `('time', 'z')`, here z is depths in ocean. I want to select and plot a varaible within a specified date range (2019-01-01 to 2020-12-31) and also range of depths (100 to 1500). I know how to select the depth range, but couldn't do the same for time. How can I choose a range of time?

I tried the following code, but the indexing of time didn't work here

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import os
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

path_in = "./"
file_ds = xr.open_dataset(path_in + 'ocean.nc')

lon = file_ds.variables['lon'][:]
lat = file_ds.variables['lat'][:]
li = file_ds.variables['depth'][0,:,0,0] 
time = file_ds.variables['time'][:]
var = file_ds.variables['var'][:,:,0,0]

index = np.intersect1d(np.where(li<-100),np.where(li>=-1500))
tindex = np.intersect1d(np.where(time<(['2020-01-01'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'),np.where(time>=['2020-12-31'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'))

var_100_1500 = var[tindex,index] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 9))
fillprof = ax.contourf(time[tindex],li[index],var_100_1500.T,levels=40)

clb=plt.colorbar(fillprof, orientation="vertical", pad=0.02)
clb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=18)
```

The error while ploting is as below

```
  tindex = np.intersect1d(np.where(time<(['2020-01-01'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'),np.where(time>=['2020-12-31'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work? can you provide a traceback?

Comment: It is a syntax error with 'tindex'. ```tindex = np.intersect1d(np.where(time<(['2020-01-01'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'),np.where(time>=['2020-12-31'],dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code which generates the error and the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback)? See the guide to [ask]

Comment: Generally though a syntax error just means you have a typo leading to invalid python. So this isn’t an xarray problem - it’s something like an extra parenthesis, comma, quote etc.

Comment: By my count you don’t close all your parens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing a ")" at the end of the tindex assignment line.

It should look like this:

```
tindex = np.intersect1d(np.where(time<(['2020-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'), np.where(time>=['2020-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')))
```